# Drawing class diagram for class with many similar methods

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Has anybody ever dealt with the class with many similar methods(e.g: `GetIntVal()`,`GetFloatValue()`,`GetStrVal()`, `GetIntVecVal()`,`GetFloatVecVal()` and etc, more than 20!) when drawing a class diagram?

How to make the class diagram clear and clean?

Answer (score 1):

You are not obliged to show every operation of a class in a diagram. You could as well add a comment as to how the many operations are named and show only a few of them "in real" while the rest can be guessed from the comment.

However, I would just leave them away all along in most places for brevity and create a single extra diagram showing the full extent.